# rubygem update (eg: thor) failing in chef

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra

I have two stanzas in my recipe:

```
    Chef::Config[:rubygems_url]='http://localbox/gems' #ghetto-for-ghetto
    [
    # :
     %w(thor <0.20.3) ,
    # :
    ].each do |g,v|
      gem_package g do
        version     v if v
#        action      :remove
        action      :purge   # Mjolnir
      end
    end
```

and

```
    [
    # :
     %w(thor =0.20.3) ,
    # :
    ].each do |g,v|
      gem_package g do
        version     v if v
     end
    end
```

My invocation seems good, but then bails:

```
: 
   * gem_package[thor] action purge (up to date)
:
:
   * gem_package[thor] action install

     ================================================================================
     Error executing action `install` on resource 'gem_package[thor]'
     ================================================================================

     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
     ------------------------------------
     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
     ---- Begin output of /usr/bin/gem install thor -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "=0.20.3" --clear-sources --source=https://www.rubygems.org --no-user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc ----
     STDOUT:
     STDERR: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EEXIST)
         File exists - (/usr/local/bin/thor)
     ---- End output of /usr/bin/gem install thor -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "=0.20.3" --clear-sources --source=https://www.rubygems.org --no-user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc ----
     Ran /usr/bin/gem install thor -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "=0.20.3" --clear-sources --source=https://www.rubygems.org --no-user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc returned 1

     Resource Declaration:
     ---------------------
     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/fake/recipes/default.rb

     121:   gem_package g do
     122:     version   v if v
     123:     options   '--no-user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc'
     124:     clear_sources     true
     125: #    gem_binary       '/usr/bin/gem'
     126:  end
     127: end

     Compiled Resource:
     ------------------
     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/fake/recipes/default.rb:121:in `block in from_file'

     gem_package("thor") do
       package_name "thor"
       action [:install]
       default_guard_interpreter :default
       declared_type :gem_package
       cookbook_name "fake"
       recipe_name "default"
       version "=0.20.3"
       options "--no-user-install --no-ri --no-rdoc"
       clear_sources true
       gem_binary "/usr/bin/gem"
     end
:
```

And, for fun, here's an initial attempt to get chef to look up:

```
# more /root/.gemrc
---
gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
:verbose: false
:update_sources: true
install: --no-wrappers --no-user-install --conservative --minimal-deps
update: --no-wrappers --no-user-install --conservative --minimal-deps
:disable_default_gem_server: true
:sources:
- http://localbox/gems/
```

Questions:

1. How hard does one have to hammer in a custom rubygems source before it sticks?  To be clear, we're a modestly secure environment, and few/no hosts can contact the Outside on their own.
2. when is a purged gem still a gem?  Did I stutter when I ordered the purge?

```
    # gem list --local thor

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    thor (0.19.1)
```

3. if gems can coexist with multiple versions, any ideas why this one can't?
4. is this kind of dependency hell not supposed to be rare with ruby?
5. really, though, my goal is the upgrade of the gem, which isn't actually possible, so my plan B is to smite the old version with the force of an angry god if need be.  Can anyone see where my plan falls apart?

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you are missing prerequisite libraries (dependencies).  I recommend you manually try to install the rubygem and then, once you know how to do it, leverage chef.

The best way to bundle rubygems is probably by using [bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler) to manage a [Gemfile](https://bundler.io/gemfile.html).  In your case, the Gemfile should look something like...

```
$ cat Gemfile 
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "http://localbox/gems"

gem "thor", "0.20.3"
```

This should govern your required rubygems.

Of course, you can again leverage chef to to run bundler for you by using [`poise-ruby`](https://github.com/poise/poise-ruby#bundle_install) cookbook:

```
bundle_install '/path/to/Gemfile' do
  deployment true
  jobs 3
end
```

Comment: I should add:  the history of the host in question begins about 15 minutes earlier, when I was able to gem-install thor -v 0.19.0 on a fresh host without issue (and without dependency complaints).  Is thor just a weak gemblob?

Comment: @user2066657: not sure how is it related to your question and my answer. if i answered your question, would appreciate if your could accept it and mark as solved. otherwise, please edit or have another question.

Comment: The fact that's a fresh host, no change to the recommendations?  No insight on thor's packaging or self-conflict over the symlink?